# How Object is created in the catch block?

Tags: java, object, exception

Generally we use "new" keyword for creating the object and I am aware that (String s = "Hello") will also create an object but in the catch block its just mentioned that `catch(ArithmeticException e)`. How 'e' is an object here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    try  {  
        int data=50/0; //may throw exception   
    }  
        //handling the exception  
    catch(ArithmeticException e)  {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  
    System.out.println("rest of the code");  
  }        
}
```

Comment: The same way that your `args` are an object. The caller / runtime actually creates the object and passes it / assigns it. You do not create the exception, the exception *is* created for you.

Comment: How is `args` an object in the main method?! Think about that ;-)

Comment: Your post states it already: `//may throw exception` - that's where the exception is created (by the VM in this case - note that `x/0` _will_ throw that exception). The `catch(ArithmeticException e)` is just where the exception is handled (i.e. caught).

Comment: You're not creating an object here, the runtime is. You also don't create the `System.out` object, it is provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

The code here in the try block when throws an exception of type ArithmeticException, the object is what is created in the runtime.
Hence, in the catch block, variable e becomes an object at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking how the `ArithmeticException` is created in your example.  (You are clearly not explicitly using `new` to create it in this case.)

The answer is that the JVM creates it.  When the JVM detects that an integer divide by zero occurs, it creates an instance of `ArithmeticException` with the message string "divide by zero" (or some such) and then it throws it.

Q: How does it detect the divide by zero and how does it create and throw the exception?

A: All of those things are implementation specific<sup>1</sup>.  But you *won't* see any specific bytecode instructions to do this if you disassemble the bytecodes.  It is happening at a lower level.  Conceptually, it happens *inside* the division instruction.

At any rate, the `ArithmeticException` object *does* get created, and then the exception handler binds it (assigns it) to the `e` variable.

---

<sup>1 - For example, on some hardware an integer divide by zero triggers an interrupt.  This will be caught by the OS exception handlers which signals the JVM.  Eventually, the signal handler (deep in the JVM) figures out which thread did it, creates the exception object and "throws" it.  It is messy complicated low-level stuff ... that you don't need to know about when writing Java programs.</sup>